# More Advanced Control Over Delayed Job workers retry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

So I'm using Delayed::Job workers (on Heroku) as an after_create callback after a user creates a certain model.

A common use case, though, it turns out, is for users to create something, then immediately delete it (likely because they made a mistake or something).

When this occurs the workers are fired up, but by the time they query for the model at hand, it's already deleted, BUT because of the auto-retry feature, this ill-fated job will retry 25 times, and definitely never work.

Is there any way I can catch certain errors and, when they occur, prevent that specific job from ever retrying again, but if it's not that error, it will retry in the future?

Answer (score 3):

Abstract the checks into the function you call with delayed_job. Make the relevant checks wether your desired job can proceed or not and either work on that job or return success.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on David's answer,  instead of doing this:

```
def after_create
   self.send_later :spam_this_user
end
```

I'd do this:

```
# user.rb

def after_create
   Delayed::Job.enqueue SendWelcomeEmailJob.new(self.id)
end

# send_welcome_email_job.rb

class SendWelcomeEmailJob <  Struct(:user_id)
   def perform
      user = User.find_by_id(self.user_id)
      return if user.nil?  #user must have been deleted

      # do stuff with user
   end
end
```

Comment: But that's hideous, vs. their otherwise lovely non-impacting design :)  I guess another real question is - do the 25 failures really cause problems?

Comment: The jobs should be resilient to errors and be re-runnable.  If that's not the case then you should either a) re-think the design of the delayed job or b) make sure that the job understands what errors it can "handle" and do the appropriate thing.  It might be to silently exit, to avoid an error causing a re-run.